# Pandas Sorting Values in Data Frames with Keys

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting

I have two Pandas dataframes that are concatenated by column.  The left dataframe is keyed as "Old" and the right dataframe is keyed as "New".  Each dataframe has the same column names and I'd like to be about to sort_values by one of the "New" columns.  I can't seem to access sort though due to the "Old" and "New" keys.  Anyone have a work around?  Thanks.

Edit#1 - Code example (want to sort by ['New']['Col1'] in df_combined:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Col2' : [4, 4, 5, 6], 'Col3' : [11, 
12, 13, 14]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : [7, 1, 51, 6], 'Col2' : [90, 99, 99, 97], 'Col3' : 
[11, 12, 13, 14]})
df_combined=pd.concat([df1, df2], axis='columns', keys=['Old','New'])
```

Comment: Please show your input dataframe.

Comment: Updated Scott.  Thanks!

Comment: How do you want to sort this dataframe exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort this dataframe you must use tuples for column selection:

```
df_combined.sort_values(by=('New', 'Col1'))
```

Output:

```
   Old            New          
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col1 Col2 Col3
1    2    4   12    1   99   12
3    4    6   14    6   97   14
0    1    4   11    7   90   11
2    3    5   13   51   99   13
```